# How to change ion-range value base on ion-input?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to make ion-range with input. First, when I using ion-range it getting the right value(this.selectedNominal) but when I'm trying using ion-input to change the value it doesn't changing. It still using first ion-range value.

HTML

```
<ion-list-header>
    Nominals
</ion-list-header>
<ion-item *ngFor="let b of listNom2">
    <ion-range min="{{b.min}}" max="{{b.max}}" step="{{b.step}}" [(ngModel)]="nominal2" (ngModelChange)="optionsNominal(nominal2)" color="secondary">
        <ion-label range-left style="font-weight: bolder;">{{ b.min | number:0 }}</ion-label>
        <ion-label range-right style="font-weight: bolder;">{{ b.max | number:0 }}</ion-label>
    </ion-range>
</ion-item>
<div style="text-align: center;margin-left:25%;margin-right:25%;padding-bottom:10px;">
    <ion-input maxlength="8" type="tel" [pattern]="[0-9]" (ionChange)="setValue2(nominal2)" style="border:1px solid #FF9900;border-radius:5px;" [(ngModel)]="nominal2" (ionChange)="optionsNominal(nominal2)">Rp.{{ nominal | number:0 }}</ion-input>
</div>
```

TS

```
setValue2(nominal2) {
    if(nominal2 == null || nominal2 == undefined || nominal2 == '') {
      this.nominal2 = 0
    } else {
      this.nominal2 = parseInt(nominal2);
    }

    if (this.nominal2 > 50000000) {
      this.nominal2 = 50000000;
    } else if (this.nominal2 < 3000000) {
      this.nominal2 = 3000000;
    }
  }

optionsNominal(value: any) {
    if (value == NaN || value == null || value == undefined || value == '') {
      this.selectedNominal = 0;
    } else {
      this.selectedNominal = value;
    }
  }
```

Comment: not sure but maybe you are having problem with `[(ngModel)]="nominal2"`.  Looks like all of your `<ion-range>` are bound to same model.

Comment: @BizzyBob when I change ion-range slider, the value must go to ion-input and when I change ion-input the value must goes to ion-range value but now, it doesn't.